# Replace a string in all files - Unix

Tags: bash, file, unix, terminal, replace

I am trying to replace a string `:::` with `::` for all lines in a batch of txtfiles (it can be considered as a word since there's always a space in front and behind it.

**I can do it with python like below, but is there a less 'over-kill' / convoluted way of doing this through the unix terminal?** (Many pipes allowed)

```
indir = "./td/"
outdir =  './od/'
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(indir,"*")):
  _,FILENAME = os.path.split()
  for l in codecs.open(infile,'r','utf8').readlines():
    l = l.replace(":::","::").strip()
    outfile = codecs.open(os.path.join(outdir,FILENAME),'a+','utf8')
    print>>outfile, l
```

Then i move all files from od to td `mv ./od/* ./td/*`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
find . -name "./td/*.c" -exec sed -i "s/:::/::/g" '{}' \;
```

No need for `od/` at all.

**EDIT:**

A slightly simpler variation:

```
ls td/*.c | xargs sed -i '' "s/:::/::/g"
```

Comment: Simpler and much more efficient as well. You can make the `find` version just as efficient if you use `+` instead of `\;` at the end.

Comment: -1 for using ls to handle file names. I would add another one for missing the obvious "simpler" solution `sed -i ... td/*.c` (with a globstar added if needed). And another one for using directory names in find's -name option (see: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm)... How did this get 4 votes ?

Comment: @Sorin: I admit I don't account for special characters in source file names (figuring that those who use them deserve what they get), but apart from that I don't see the problem. Kudos for your `td/*.c` suggestion though, I didn't know that would work; I'd've added it to my answer (with attribution) if it had been suggested with more courtesy.

Comment: I don't know if I need to laugh or to cry.`
sorin@sorin:~/tmp$ find -name "./tc/*.c" 
find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  That means that '-name `./tc/*.c'' will probably evaluate to false all the time on this system.  You might find the '-wholename' test more useful, or perhaps '-samefile'.  Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep, you could use 'find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ `./tc/*.c''.`

Answer (score 3):

A simple loop to process each file with `sed` should suffice.

```
for inp in ./td/*; do
    fname=${inp##*/}
    sed 's/:::/::/g' "$inp" > ./od/"$fname"
done
```