# Can I create Variable Names from Constants in Objective-C/Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

This question is related to Swift and Objective-C.

I want to create variables from Constant Strings. So, in future, when I change name of a variable though out app, I just need to change it at one place, it must be changed, wherever it is used.

Example:

I have `user_id` in 14 files, if I want to change `user_id` into `userID` I have to change in all 14 files, but I want to change at once place only.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use the Xcode build process and add a script (language can be of your choice, but the default is a BASH script)

1. Create string constant text file where you define all your variables you want to change in some format that expresses the change you want to make, for example:

   "variable_one_name" = "new_variable_one_name"

Depending on how 'smart' you wanted your script to be you could also list all your variables and include some way of indicating when a variable is not to be replaced.

```
"variable_one_name" = "new_variable_one_name"
"variable_two_name" = "DO_NOT_CHANGE"
```

2. Run a pre build script on you project that reads in the string constant text file and then iterates through your source files and executes the desired replacement. Be careful to limit the directories you search to you OWN source files!
3. build project...

This would allow you to manage your constants from one place. However it clearly is only going to help you after you have created a project and written some code :)

[BASH string replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230865/replace-a-string-in-all-files-unix)

[Adding a run script to the Xcode build process](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaRunScriptBuildPhase.html)

Comment: Nice answer but not what the OP seems to be asking. Personally I generally use TextWrangler which can perform one change across all files. I have also written programs to handle all files in a directory to replace non-ASCII characters and CR -> LF.

Comment: @zaph, I can't do this in iOS, while in PHP, it can be done as 

 define("Test", "testabc");

  ${Test} = "test value";

  echo ${Test}; exit;


So, what do you say. any idea?

Comment: @fragilecat , I can also do, it using Find and Replace, but what If I use Strings which are coming from server to make variables?

Comment: Different question, this is why it is important to provide information on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Then you would have to adjust your workflow to accommodate this change. I cannot tell you how since I do not know your current workflow.

Comment: @zaph, I want to make variables, from Strings, or Values assigned to Constants. 

Is it clear Sir

Comment: Sam Shaikh:  Until today there was no mention of a server being involved, that is a change in workflow. I so if you need to get those strings from a server you would have to fetch them from the server then build your constants file. You could have that server component be part of the run script in Xcode.

Comment: Means, you want to say that I can create variables from Constants using ONLY SCRIPTS in BASH. RIGHT? @fragilecat,

Comment: Essedntially thee scheme of using server variable names is flawed. How would you handle a server variable name 1id1 which is reserved in ObjC? You really need to find another scheme, there are several available including RestKit.

Comment: Involvement of server or without it, remains same question, I want to create a variable from a String, Lets say #define FOO "user_id"      , In .h NSString *FOO; So it must take name as user_id, from Constant.